# express (4.0) custom middleware runs on both instances of router even though it's only declared for one

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url-routing

I'm using the code below to learn a bit about the new express.js (4.0). I can't seem to understand why the logging is happening regardless of which path I hit with my browser. Shouldn't it only log for `website.get` and not for `api.get` paths?

```
// Express 4.0 test...

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var website = express.Router();
var api = express.Router();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

website.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.method, req.url);
  next();
});

website.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Home page');
});
website.get('/about', function (req, res) {
  res.send('About page');
});

api.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send({'json':'response'});
});

api.get('/user', function (req, res) {
  res.send({'user':'john'});
});

// app.get('/', function (request, response) {
//  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
//  response.end("<h1>Hello, World!</h1>");
// });

app.use('/', website);
app.use('/api', api);

app.listen(port);
console.log('http(s) server revved up on port ' + port);
```

Any help would rock!

**Update:** I see, because `'/api'` matches `'/'`, website gets applied to all routes. Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

probably define the /api router first and the other one - second.

```
app.use('/api', api);
app.use('/', website);
```

Comment: Middleware is processed in order of route handling (see: http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/03/10/express-js-middleware-demystified/)